# How To Change Backbone Dynamic URL with Backbone Events/Vent?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, single-page-application

**Edited This Below**

In this image below I have two main regions.

One for the user list on the left: **allusersRegion**

And  another for the the right side where a layout is displayed, which contains unique attributes to the user that was clicked in the **allusersRegion** and a list of articles by the user: middleCoreRegion

**If you noticed the middleCoreRegion is showing all articles by all users..This is wrong and I am trying to show all articles of the individual user (in this case. "kev")

[image]

I tried to see if my problem was with my JSON api (served via node/rest/mongoose) or with my underscore templates, but if it displays both list then I suppose I need to filter from inside backbone.

At first I tried using a Marionette.vent to simply change the url, but somhow I can't get the _id name into the url: function(), it says undefined...

```
var someuser = this.model.get("_id"); 
myApp.vent.trigger("showarticles", someuser);
```

I add a listener in the backbone collection on the same page:

```
myApp.vent.on("showarticles", someuser);
```

**The Edit (A Different Way of Doing this) Here is my code

```
var usertab = Poplive.module('usertab', {
    startWithParent: true,       
});

usertab.addInitializer(function() {

User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
UniqueArticle = Backbone.Model.extend({});

//Collections
Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: User,
url: '/api/user2'
});

UniqueArticles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: UniqueArticle,
url:  '/api/survey'
});

//Layout
var VisitingLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: "#visiting-layout",
  regions: {
    firstRegion: "#listone",
    secondRegion: "#listtwo",
    thirdRegion: "#listthree",
    playRegion: "#playhere",
    articlesRegion: "#articleshere" 
  }
});

AllUserView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
template: "#tab-alluser-template",
tagName: 'li',
events:  {
  "click #openprofile" : "OpenProfile"
},

OpenProfile: function(){
  console.log("Profile is open for " + this.model.get("username"));
  var modelo = this.model.get("_id");
  var vlv = new VisitingLayoutView({model: this.model});
  Poplive.middleCoreRegion.show(vlv);

var ua = new UniqueArticles();
var uacoll = new UniqueArticlesView({collection: ua});
vlv.articlesRegion.show(uacoll);
}
})

//ItemViews
UniqueArticleView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
template: "#unique-article-template"
});

//CollectionViews
AllUsersView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
   template: "#tab-allusers-template",
   itemView: AllUserView
});

UniqueArticlesView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  template: "#unique-articles-template",
  itemView: UniqueArticleView
});

//Render Views
var alluserview = new AllUserView();
var allusersview = new AllUsersView();

//Fetch Collections
var theusers = new Users();
theusers.fetch();
var userscoll = new AllUsersView({collection: theusers});
Poplive.allusersRegion.show(userscoll);
           });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming  `UniqueArticle`  to be the Backbone Model, for the Model with a specific id to be fetched you would need to define the urlRoot property which will append the `id` of the model to the request.

So the id attribute will be appended to the end of the request the model from the server when you do a fetch on it

```
  var UniqueArticle = Backbone.Model.extend({
      idAttribute : 'someuser',
      urlRoot : function(someuser){
          return '/api/visitingarticles/'
      }
       // this would send a request for 
        //  /api/visitingarticles/someId
    });

    var UniqueArticles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: Article,
      url : function(someuser){
          return '/api/visitingarticles/'
      }
      //  /api/visitingarticles   -- All Articles will be fetched
    });
```

Comment: I tried this out, but does not work. Somehow i'm unable to bring the variable into the url function, its says 'UNDEFINED' in the console.log.

Comment: Did you specify the `idattribute` for the model

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want, is to define `url` as a function, and have a `user` attribute on your collection:

```
var UniqueArticles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Article,

  initialize: function(){
    var self = this;
    myApp.vent.on("showarticles", function(someuser){
        self.user = someuser;
        self.fetch();
    }
  },

  url : function(){
      var fragment = '/api/visitingarticles/';
      if(this.user && this.user.id){
        return fragment + this.user.id;
      }
      return fragment;
  }
});
```

(Disclaimer: untested code, but it works in my head :D)

Then each time you trigger the event, the `user`attribute is updated, the collection is reset with the updated url.

As a side note, you might want to look into using a filtered collection. I've implemented that idea in my book, based on Derick Bailey's code here: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/7tvzF/

Here is my version: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/entities/common.js

And an example of its use (lines 38-41): https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L38

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this out, but unfortunately im unable to use any variable or object declared outside of the URL function. For example when I try to use 'this.user.id' console.log say 'UNDEFINED', even though it gives a value outside of the URL function. 

I edited my question above with a picture and my full code in case it helps.

Secondly I looked into the filtered collection, so decided that may be another way. btw I checked out your book and tutorials the other day, they've been a great help.